# Suppose an airport metal detector catches a person with metal 99% of the time. That is, it misses detecting a person with metal 1% of the time.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Suppose an airport metal detector catches a person with metal 99% of the time. That is, it misses detecting a person with metal 1% of the time. Assume independence of people carrying metal. What is the probability that the first metal-carrying person missed (not detected) is among the first 50 metal-carrying persons scanned?

Can someone explain why we need negative binomial distribution to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let’s assume all 100 persons are carrying metal through the machine.

The odds that one person will be mis-detected  and get through are 100%.

If there were only 50 persons, the odds of machine misdetecting are 50%.

If not all persons try to carry metal through, the question is what are the odds the machine will misdetect the one people in first 50 that actually carries metal through?

The answer to that question is this: we know for sure the machine has 50% odds to misedetect in the first batch of 50 people. We don’t know what are the odds that the person misdetected actually carried metal.

We can’t possibly know that. It could be that all 50, or some or no one actually tried to carry metal through. It is very possible that the machine malfunctioned when a person that didn’t carry metal actually went through.

So this is the deal: in the most conservative appreciation, all 50 carried metal through. The odds of machine malfunction are 50%.

If only 50% of the people carried metal through, intently or not, then the odds of machine misdetecting the one person in 50 that carried metal are 50%x50%=25%.

On the same logic, if only 30% carried metal, the odds of misdetection are 15%.

If we knew the odds of a person carrying metal, we can calculate the odds that person got through. Since we don’t know that, we can’t possibly tell that the machine missed the metal-carrier in first 50 persons with any probability.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Let $P_n$ be the $n^{\Bbb {th}}$ person carrying metal. The probability of $P_n$ be the first to be missed is $$\left(\frac{99}{100}\right)^{n-1}\frac1{100}$$

Therefore the probability of the first person to be missed is among $P_1,P_2,...P_{50}$ is $$\sum_{n=1}^{50}\left(\frac{99}{100}\right)^{n-1}\frac1{100}\\=\frac{\frac1{100}\left(\left(\frac{99}{100}\right)^{50}-1\right)}{\frac{99}{100}-1}\\=1-\left(\frac{99}{100}\right)^{50}$$

Another possible way is to use complement event. The complement of this event is no one is missed among the first 50 people. The probability of no one got missed is $\left(\frac{99}{100}\right)^{50}$. Thus the complement's probability is $1-\left(\frac{99}{100}\right)^{50}$

Answer (score 1):

You can just calculate the chance that the first $50$ people are all caught.  The chance each one is caught is $0.99$ so the chance they are all caught is $0.99^{50}\approx 0.605$.  The chance the first one missed is within the first $50$ is $1-0.99^{50}\approx 0.395$